# Java8 lambda remove element from List<?> and update the boolean flag value

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8

I've to set one flag `nameRemoved=true`, when I remove some object from the `List<String>`

This what traditional approach I'm using here.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
if (list.contains("abc")) {
    list.remove("abc");
    nameRemoved=true
}
```

I can remove element from the list using below but how can I also set the flag value to `nameRemoved=true` using lambda syntaxes ?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.removeIf(name -> name.equalsIgnoreCase("abc"));
```

Comment: nameRemoved = list.removeIf(name -> name.equalsIgnoreCase("abc")) or safer 
removedName = test.removeIf("abc"::equalsIgnoreCase);

Comment: Awesome  .. put it as a answer please

Comment: Your “traditional approach” was not case insensitive and only removed one occurence, so it’s an entirely different operation than your `removeIf(…)` example. The only thing they have in common, is you ignoring the return value. The first code can be written as simple as `nameRemoved = list.remove("abc");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As op requested I put my comment as an answer.
Because removeIf return true if any element was removed you can set your flag based on the result.

```java
nameRemoved = list.removeIf(name -> name.equalsIgnoreCase("abc"))
```

Or safer and with a method reference:

```java
nameRemoved = list.removeIf("abc"::equalsIgnoreCase);
```

EDIT:
As @Holger commented this answer only focus on how to replace the code with the removeIf. But this code is quite different from the first one. The first one remove only one element from the list that match exactly the given string. The one I provided will remove all element that match ignoring the case.

Answer (score 3):

`RemoveIf` returns a boolean so you can do this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean nameRemoved = list.removeIf(name -> "abc".equalsIgnoreCase(name));
```

or

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean nameRemoved = list.removeIf("abc"::equalsIgnoreCase);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: Might raise a `NPE` you should reverse comparison `"abc".equalsIgnoreCase(name)`